# Data source doesn't refresh contents while planning

Tags: terraform, datasource, vault, terraform-provider-vault

```
data "vault_generic_secret" "nr" {
  path = "secret/secrets"
}
```

I have this code to fetch data from Vault. I have added a new secret(newrelic_license_key) in the same vault location and while running terraform plan I am getting the following error:

```
"newrelic_license_key" does not exist in map data.vault_generic_secret.nr.data in:

${data.vault_generic_secret.nr.data["newrelic_license_key"]}
```

According to the data source documentation
https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources#data-resource-behavior

> At least one of the given arguments is a managed resource attribute or other value that Terraform cannot predict until the apply step

Due to this I think data source should refresh secrets while applying and should not error out in the plan.

TF version: v0.11.15
Vault Provider Version: "< 3.0.0"

Comment: Shouldn't this be a separate path?

Comment: As of now it is not.

Comment: Seems like an issue with tf 0.11 tried with 1.1.0 not facing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform Version Upgrade resolved the issue.